# Checkbox Toggle button: Activate TADOQuery when image is checked

Tags: delphi

I'm doing a `toggle switch`, that when I click it changes its `On/off` state, I created it by overriding the `Paint` method in `TCanvas`, everything fine but the borders looked pixelated.

So I modified the component to load an image for each state depending on the checked of the image, in short I'm putting a `TImage` component inside a `Checkbox` inherited from `TwwCheckbox`

But when the image is pressed/clicked/checked, the `Checked` changes its state to true but it doesn't show the state that was saved in the database the next time I reopen the form, I mean, if I activate the `toggle` it is saved with an `S` and when opening the form where the `Toggle` is, it should be On and not off

```
{here I create the toggle in runtime and assign it a datasource
to connect it to the database}
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject); 
begin    
   ToggleButton:= TinToggleButton2.Create(Self);    
   ToggleButton.Name := 'ToggleButton';    
   ToggleButton.Parent:= Self;    
   ToggleButton.Left:= 200;    
   ToggleButton.Top:=100;    
   ToggleButton.Visible:= true;    
   ToggleButton.ValueChecked:= 'S';    
   ToggleButton.ValueUnchecked:= 'N';    
   ToggleButton.DisplayValueChecked:= 'S';    
   ToggleButton.DisplayValueUnchecked:= 'N';    
   ToggleButton.DataField:= 'TAutoSave';    
   ToggleButton.DataSource:= dsToggleButton;    
   ToggleButton.DataSource.DataSet:= qryToggleButton; 
end;

//here the query 
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  qryToggleButton.Active:= true;
end;

//i send the data to database
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  qryToggleButton.Post;
end;

{here I create the component in another unit where the click event is
to switch between image}
constructor TinToggleButton2.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Width:= 34;
  Height:= 15;
  Image:= TImage.Create(Self);
  Image.Visible:= true;
  Image.Picture.LoadFromFile('toggle_Toggle1.ico');
  Image.Parent:= Self;
  Image.OnClick:=Self.Image1Click;
  Self.Checked:= false;
 Checked:= false;
end;

procedure TinToggleButton2.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
   if DataSource <> nil then
    begin
      DataSource.Edit;
      if Self.Checked then
        begin
           Self.Checked:= false;
           DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName(DataField).Value:= ValueUnchecked;
           Image.Picture.LoadFromFile('toggle_Toggle1.ico');
        end
   else
      begin
         Self.Checked:= true;
         DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName(DataField).Value:= ValueChecked;
         Image.Picture.LoadFromFile('toggle_Toggle2.ico');
      end;
  end;
end;
```

I create the toggle in runtime but I put the other components such as the `TwwDataSource` and the `TADOQuery` in the form and I assign the `DataField` and the `DataSource` to the checkbox

Comment: FillPath, SolidBrush are basically just GDI methods from the win 32 api, so there would be equivalents in Delphi, if not you could likely call the api directly

Comment: Using Delphi, the class TCanvas implement GDI. Graphics components have a property Canvas that you can use in your Paint routine.

Comment: You put a dataset into edit or insert mode by calling it's `Edit` or `Insert` methods, not by calling `Open`. It has to first be opened, and then either edited or a new row inserted. You can't call `Post` unless you've first called either `Edit` or `Insert`, and should only be calling `Post` if the data was actually changed.

Comment: @KenWhite yeah but the component put in `edit state` each time I change the `checkbox`, what I did was `if DataSource <> nil then DataSource.Edit` and in the `Checked` put its `DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName(DataField).Value:= ValueUnchecked`  and it works